# Expression Interactivity Data Trigger Does Not Correctly Display Bound Value Originally

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I have an Expression Interactivity `DataTrigger` that changes the `Text` property of a `TextBlock` based on a bound `TimeSpan` property. When that value is greater-than-or-equal-to `Timespan.Zero`, the text will be the value of the property. When the value is less than zero, the value changes to "??:??:??".

The relevant code is as follows:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InspectionService.TimeRemainingForPart}" Comparison="GreaterThanOrEqual" Value="{x:Static sys:TimeSpan.Zero}">
        <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Text" Value="{Binding InspectionService.TimeRemainingForPart}" />
    </ei:DataTrigger>

    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InspectionService.TimeRemainingForPart}" Comparison="LessThan" Value="{x:Static sys:TimeSpan.Zero}">
        <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Text" Value="??:??:??" />
    </ei:DataTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The `TimeRemainingForPart` property is updated via a timer in the `InspectionService`. When the timer is running, everything is fine. When the timer is stopped (which will set the `TimeRemainingForPart` to Timespan.Zero), the View shows "00:00:00" as expected. However, when the application first loads, there is nothing displayed in the text block. I've even tried changing the value/notifying the property changing from the constructor of `InspectionService` and nothing happens.

I can always just go to a standard WPF DataTrigger with a converter called "TimespanLessThanZeroConverter" or somesuch, but any idea as to why the current way I'm doing it doesn't work when the application starts-up?

Edit:  Forgot to mention I had tried calling OnPropertyChanged on the TimeRemainingForPart property in my constructor for the service just in case something wasn't getting notified correctly, but that didn't seem to accomplish anything.

Edit2:  Adding full XAML for Textblock and the relevant sections of the ViewModel and Service.

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" FontSize="56" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding InspectionService.TimeRemainingForPart}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource StatusIndicatorTextBlockStyle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InspectionService.InspectionExecutionState}" Value="{x:Static enum:InspectionExecutionStates.Paused}">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Transparent" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard Duration="0:0:1">
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="White" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InspectionService.TimeRemainingForPart}" Comparison="GreaterThanOrEqual" Value="{x:Static sys:TimeSpan.Zero}">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Text" Value="{Binding InspectionService.TimeRemainingForPart}" />
        </ei:DataTrigger>

        <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InspectionService.TimeRemainingForPart}" Comparison="LessThan" Value="{x:Static sys:TimeSpan.Zero}">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Text" Value="??:??:??" />
        </ei:DataTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : IMyViewModel
{
    public IInspectionService InspectionService { get; private set; }

    public MyViewModel (IInspectionService inspectionService)
    {
        this.InspectionService = inspectionService;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class InspectionService : BindableBase, IInspectionService
{
    private readonly IModeService _modeService;
    private readonly IRemainingTimeFileServiceFactory _remainingTimeFileServiceFactory;

    private string _inspectionCell;

    private readonly DispatcherTimer _timeRemainingForPartTimer;

    #region IInspectionService Members

    private InspectionExecutionStates _inspectionExecutionState;
    public InspectionExecutionStates InspectionExecutionState
    {
        get { return this._inspectionExecutionState; }
        private set { this.SetProperty(ref this._inspectionExecutionState, value); }

    private string _inspectionName;
    public string InspectionName
    {
        get { return this._inspectionName; }
        private set { this.SetProperty(ref this._inspectionName, value); }
    }

    private TimeSpan _timeRemainingForPart;
    public TimeSpan TimeRemainingForPart
    {
        get { return this._timeRemainingForPart; }
        private set { this.SetProperty(ref this._timeRemainingForPart, value); }

    private TimeSpan _totalTimeRemaining;
    public TimeSpan TotalTimeRemaining
    {
        get { return this._totalTimeRemaining; }
        private set { this.SetProperty(ref this._totalTimeRemaining, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    public InspectionService(IModeService modeService, IRemainingTimeFileServiceFactory remainingTimeFileServiceFactory)
    {
        this._modeService = modeService;
        this._remainingTimeFileServiceFactory = remainingTimeFileServiceFactory;

        this._timeRemainingForPartTimer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
        this._timeRemainingForPartTimer.Tick += this.TimeRemainingForPartTimerOnTick;
    }

    private void StartSelectedInspection(InspectionPlanInfo inspectionPlanInfo)
    {
        this.SetInspectionProperties(inspectionPlanInfo);
        this.StartInspection
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private void StartInspection()
    {
        this.TotalTimeRemaining = this._remainingTimeFileServiceFactory.GetIRemainingTimeFileService(this._inspectionCell).GetInspectionTime(this.InspectionName);
        this.TimeRemainingForPart = this._modeService.IsStudyActive ? TimeSpan.MinValue : this.TotalTimeRemaining;
        this._timeRemainingForPartTimer.Start();
    }

    private void StopInspection()
    {
        this.ClearInspectionProperties();
        this._timeRemainingForPartTimer.Stop();
    }

    private void SetInspectionProperties(InspectionPlanInfo inspectionPlanInfo)
    {
        this.InspectionName = inspectionPlanInfo.InspectionName;
        this._inspectionCell = inspectionPlanInfo.Cell;
    }

    private void ClearInspectionProperties()
    {
        this.InspectionName = "";
        this.TimeRemainingForPart = TimeSpan.Zero;
        this.TotalTimeRemaining = TimeSpan.Zero;
    }

    private void TimeRemainingForPartTimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (this.TimeRemainingForPart < TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            this._timeRemainingForPartTimer.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            this.TimeRemainingForPart -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            this.TotalTimeRemaining -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 3:

So apparently it can't be done without a converter so the TextBlock code is modified as follows:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" FontSize="56" FontWeight="Bold">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource StatusIndicatorTextBlockStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding InspectionService.TimeRemainingForPart}" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InspectionService.TimeRemainingForPart, Converter={StaticResource TimespanLessThanZeroConverter}}"
                        Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="??:??:??" />
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InspectionService.InspectionExecutionState}" Value="{x:Static enum:InspectionExecutionStates.Paused}">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Transparent" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard Duration="0:0:1">
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="White" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

And for completeness/posterity sake the converter looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace CurrentInspection.Converters
{
    public class TimespanLessThanZeroConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!(value is TimeSpan))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return (TimeSpan)value < TimeSpan.Zero;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you binding the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to the source property like this?:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding InspectionService.TimeRemainingForPart}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InspectionService.TimeRemainingForPart}" Comparison="LessThan" Value="{x:Static sys:TimeSpan.Zero}">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Text" Value="??:??:??" />
        </ei:DataTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Then it should just be a matter of setting the `TimeRemainingForPart` property to the default value in the constructor of the view model.

As you have noticed I have removed the first interaction trigger. You better bind the Text property to the source property and use a converter instead of using two `ChangePropertyAction`s. Or bind to a string property of the view model that returns the correct string based on the `TimeSpan` value.

Comment: The setting to default would happen in the constructor for the service, actually (which inherits `BindableBase` from Prism). But I already tried calling OnPropertyChanged from the constructor thinking that might work, but it didn't. (I should probably update my question to indicate I tried this.)

Comment: Please include the full markup of your TextBlock and your view model.

Comment: What's the purpose of the first DataTrigger? What if you remove it?

Comment: Purpose of the first data trigger is to indicate the user that the counter has paused when they hit the pause button by animating the time display. Removing does not fix the problem.

Comment: I mean the first trigger in <i:Interaction.Triggers>.

Comment: You just need the LessThan trigger and a default value.

Comment: Sorry. It's needed because interactivity triggers don't work like normal WPF triggers. They permanently change the value of the property. So I need that to change it back otherwise I will have nothing but ??:??:?? for the rest of the lifetime of that TextBlock. (I'm guessing this is a parallel to why standard WPF DataTriggers cannot exist out of styles and cannot overwrite property values set outside of styles.)

But I will say that removing it will render the 00:00:00 properly upon startup.

Comment: I was afraid the answer was going to be "you can't do that".

Oh, well, converter it is then. (See question for final TextBlock markup.)